# Suddenly my desktop app can't load Google Contacts

Tags: google-oauth, google-contacts-api

my Windows application which loads Google Contacts has been working fine for years. All of a sudden (probably within the last week or so) it's as if I've deleted all my contacts. All the Oauth2/ access token stuff seems to be fine (no error messages), it just loads zero contacts, with no recent changes to the code. Does anyone know if Google have changed something their end I should know about? I can't find any mention online.
The app uses older technology (built with MFC in VS 2008) but even so?
GC

Comment: Are you able to paste any sort of error message from the server? There isn't much to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

My bad - I hadn't allocated enough memory to store the access token I was getting back from Google. But it might be of interest to know that they must have recently started sending longer ones...